# NVIDIA driver version/pytorch error message on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: ubuntu, python, drivers, nvidia, cuda

in pycharm IDE I get the following error message:

```
RuntimeError: The NVIDIA driver on your system is too old (found version 9010). Please update your GPU driver by downloading and installing a new version from the URL: http://www.nvidia.com/Download/index.aspx Alternatively, go to: https://pytorch.org to install a PyTorch version that has been compiled with your version of the CUDA driver.
```

When I run `nvcc --version` in the console I get the following:

```
nvcc: NVIDIA (R) Cuda compiler driver
Copyright (c) 2005-2017 NVIDIA Corporation
Built on Fri_Nov__3_21:07:56_CDT_2017
Cuda compilation tools, release 9.1, V9.1.85
```

When I run `modinfo nvidia` I get this one:

```
filename:       /lib/modules/4.15.0-58-generic/updates/dkms/nvidia.ko
alias:          char-major-195-*
version:        390.138
supported:      external
license:        NVIDIA
srcversion:     9CF28EA4192CED46A545E30
alias:          pci:v000010DEd00000E00sv*sd*bc04sc80i00*
alias:          pci:v000010DEd*sv*sd*bc03sc02i00*
alias:          pci:v000010DEd*sv*sd*bc03sc00i00*
depends:        ipmi_msghandler
retpoline:      Y
name:           nvidia
vermagic:       4.15.0-58-generic SMP mod_unload 
signat:         PKCS#7
signer:         
sig_key:        
sig_hashalgo:   md4
parm:           NVreg_Mobile:int
parm:           NVreg_ResmanDebugLevel:int
parm:           NVreg_RmLogonRC:int
parm:           NVreg_ModifyDeviceFiles:int
parm:           NVreg_DeviceFileUID:int
parm:           NVreg_DeviceFileGID:int
parm:           NVreg_DeviceFileMode:int
parm:           NVreg_UpdateMemoryTypes:int
parm:           NVreg_InitializeSystemMemoryAllocations:int
parm:           NVreg_UsePageAttributeTable:int
parm:           NVreg_MapRegistersEarly:int
parm:           NVreg_RegisterForACPIEvents:int
parm:           NVreg_CheckPCIConfigSpace:int
parm:           NVreg_EnablePCIeGen3:int
parm:           NVreg_EnableMSI:int
parm:           NVreg_TCEBypassMode:int
parm:           NVreg_UseThreadedInterrupts:int
parm:           NVreg_EnableStreamMemOPs:int
parm:           NVreg_EnableBacklightHandler:int
parm:           NVreg_RestrictProfilingToAdminUsers:int
parm:           NVreg_EnableUserNUMAManagement:int
parm:           NVreg_EnableIBMNPURelaxedOrderingMode:int
parm:           NVreg_MemoryPoolSize:int
parm:           NVreg_KMallocHeapMaxSize:int
parm:           NVreg_VMallocHeapMaxSize:int
parm:           NVreg_IgnoreMMIOCheck:int
parm:           NVreg_RegistryDwords:charp
parm:           NVreg_RegistryDwordsPerDevice:charp
parm:           NVreg_RmMsg:charp
parm:           NVreg_AssignGpus:charp
```

In another post I've seen that someone switched the drivers. Does somebody know how this works or has another hint for me?

Comment: has no one an idea?

Comment: Update NVIDIA Register da..don't be irresponsible